# Does a shadow effect that doesn't do anything return Mountain Warg to staging area?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

When a shadow card is dealt that has the shadow keyword but the effect doesn't do anything, does Mountain Warg go back to the staging area?

For example, "If this attack is undefended..." and the attack is defended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules refer to a "Shadow Effect Icon", the thing that separates the shadow effect text from the rest of the card's text:

> **Shadow Effect Icon:** If a card has a shadow  effect, that effect is denoted by this icon,
>   which also serves to separate the shadow effect from the card’s in
>   play effect.

As such, I take the presence of such an icon on a card to be the key factor in determining whether or not the card "has a shadow effect" in rules terms, even if the effect does not actually do anything when it resolves.